# non-static data member initialization from mother protected field

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance

I have an issue trying to use non-static data member init. in a complex template inheritance chain. I attach a small non-working example:

```
struct Builder {
    template <typename T> T& get() {
        return a;
    };

    float a = 5;
};

struct Base {
    Builder a;
};

template <typename T> struct A: public Base {};

template <typename T> struct B: public A<T> {

    float& b = (A<T>::a).get<float>(); // Do not work

    Builder& builder = A<T>::a;
    float& c = builder.get<float>(); // Work
};

struct C: public A<float> {

    float& b = a.get<float>(); // Work
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I'm most interested in `class B`. I have a compilation error using gcc 4.9.2:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
     float& b = (A<T>::a).get<float>(); // Do not work
```

I don't understand why it does not work as ti does compile if I use the trick two lines below (suffixed by the comment `Work`) which is basically the same thing.

It also works out of the box if my class is not a template. In this case, I can directly access the protected field by its name without using the syntaxe `ParentClass<T>::field`.

Do you have any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here `get` is a dependent name (it depends on `T`). You need to explicitly state it's the name of a template :

```
float& b = A<T>::a.template get<float>();
```

The second one works because you explicitly "collapse" `A<T>::a` into a `Builder&`, which does not depend on `T` anymore.

The third one works because you inherit from the fully specialized `A<float>`, which again does not depend on `T`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation I wasn't aware of such syntax! It works fine when using `template get<>`!